# Linking the Google API iOS Static Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api

I am trying to link the **Google API** into my iOS Application. I have downloaded the *google-api-objectivec-client* from their website and I am following the [first option instructions](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary) to link the static library ("Linking to the iOS Static Library").

Here was my process:

- Drag GTL.xcodeproj into my workspace.
- In my main project **Build Phases** tab, I've added GTLTouchStaticLib under **Target Dependancies**
- Then I've gone over to the **Compile Sources** tab, and I've added libGTLTouchStaticLib.a
- Under **Build Settings**, I've added '-ObjC-all_load' in the Other Linker Flags field.

Now, before Google tell you to make the Other Linker Flags changes, they tell you to:

```
The static library target also creates a folder with the library's headers to drag into your target's sources. 
The headers folder is created in the build products directory. To find build products directory, in Xcode 4's Locations preferences pane, click the arrow for Derived Data.
```

So I go ahead and do this, and the Header files are now in my target sources. So I figured that before I go ahead and add any of the services they offer, I should compile it and just make sure everything is OK. My project wouldn't compile, giving **19** compiler errors, to the tune of:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_kSecValueData", referenced from:`-[GTMOAuth2Keychain setPassword:forService:accessibility:account:error:] in` libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
```

So obviously something is going wrong here. Does anybody have any ideas? I've read some documentation and many other stack questions, and it seems that everybody has different ideas and slightly different problems and I just cant figure it out. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embarrassing that I didnt actually google part of the error code. Anyway seems I didnt include Security.framework and SystemConfiguration.framework. Ill probably need the other two they suggest sometime later too. 
Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gtm-oauth2/TVgSxG3129A/xcfsF9gmkgIJ